# Nested Tables gives unexpected table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I am working with this oracle script these days.

```
create type virus_Statistic_t as object(
    vDate date,
    infection int,
    dead int,
    recovered int
)
/

create type virus_Statistic_tlb as table of virus_Statistic_t

create type countries_t as object(
    Province_or_State varchar2(50),
    Country_or_Region varchar2(100),
    Lat Number(10,6),
    Longt Number(10,6),
    virus virus_Statistic_tlb
)
/

create table countries of countries_t (
       primary key(Province_or_State, Country_or_Region)
) nested table virus store as virus_ntb;

INSERT INTO countries VALUES (
       countries_t('British Columbia', 'Canada', 49.2827, -123.1207, 
                 virus_Statistic_tlb(
                        virus_Statistic_t('22-JAN-20', 5, 0, 0), 
                        virus_Statistic_t('23-JAN-20', 10, 2, 5)
                 )
        )
);

INSERT INTO countries VALUES (
       countries_t('Queensland', 'Australia', -28.0167, 153.4, 
                 virus_Statistic_tlb(
                        virus_Statistic_t('22-JAN-20', 20, 0, 0), 
                        virus_Statistic_t('23-JAN-20', 10, 8, 10)
                 )
        )
);

select c.Province_or_State, c.Country_or_Region, c.Lat, c.Longt,  v.vDate, v.infection, v.dead, v.recovered 
from countries c, table(c.virus) v
```

**After I ran this it gives me this table**

```
PROVINCE_OR_STATE  COUNTRY_OR_REGION    LAT         LONGT    VDATE     INFECTION    DEAD    RECOVERED
British Columbia    Canada            49.2827   -123.1207   22-JAN-20   5            0      0
British Columbia    Canada            49.2827   -123.1207   23-JAN-20   10           2      5
Queensland          Australia        -28.0167    153.4      22-JAN-20   20           0      0
Queensland          Australia        -28.0167    153.4      23-JAN-20   10           8      10
```

**But my expected table is**

```
PROVINCE_OR_STATE  COUNTRY_OR_REGION    LAT         LONGT    VDATE     INFECTION    DEAD    RECOVERED
British Columbia    Canada            49.2827   -123.1207   22-JAN-20   5            0      0
                                                            23-JAN-20   10           2      5
Queensland          Australia        -28.0167    153.4      22-JAN-20   20           0      0
                                                            23-JAN-20   10           8      10
```

What changes should I apply to my code?

You can test that script in [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ef78362426fbcfd7adb81b7366462ced)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you tagged it with SQL*Plus tag, then **break** is what you need.

This is what you have now:

```
SQL> select c.Province_or_State, c.Country_or_Region, c.Lat, c.Longt,
  2         v.vDate, v.infection, v.dead, v.recovered
  3  from countries c, table(c.virus) v;

PROVINCE_OR_STAT COUNTRY_OR_REGION           LAT      LONGT VDATE     INFECTION       DEAD  RECOVERED
---------------- -------------------- ---------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
British Columbia Canada                  49,2827  -123,1207 22.01.20          5          0          0
British Columbia Canada                  49,2827  -123,1207 23.01.20         10          2          5
```

Break:

```
SQL> break on province_or_state on country_or_region on lat on longt
SQL> select c.Province_or_State, c.Country_or_Region, c.Lat, c.Longt,
  2         v.vDate, v.infection, v.dead, v.recovered
  3  from countries c, table(c.virus) v;

PROVINCE_OR_STAT COUNTRY_OR_REGION           LAT      LONGT VDATE     INFECTION       DEAD  RECOVERED
---------------- -------------------- ---------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
British Columbia Canada                  49,2827  -123,1207 22.01.20          5          0          0
                                                            23.01.20         10          2          5

SQL>
```

Other (reporting) tools, such as Oracle Reports Builder or Apex Classic Report have their own *breaking* capabilities.

---

With another row inserted, query (actually, *break*) still works as expected:

```
SQL> /

PROVINCE_OR_STAT COUNTRY_OR_REGION           LAT      LONGT VDATE     INFECTION       DEAD  RECOVERED
---------------- -------------------- ---------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
British Columbia Canada                  49,2827  -123,1207 22.01.20          5          0          0
                                                            23.01.20         10          2          5
Queensland       Australia              -28,0167      153,4 22.01.20         20          0          0
                                                            23.01.20         10          8         10

SQL>
```

Comment: What will happen if I want to add another province and country. Are them breaking also?

Comment: They will automatically be broken :) It is not *contents* you specify, but *column names* you're breaking on.

Comment: I have got `Province_or_State` and `Country_or_Region` as composite keys. technically it cannot be repeated same.  If I will have to enter another country I want it without break.

Comment: Try to insert another row (or a few of them) to see how it behaves.

Comment: I think my question is not very clear I have updated my question by inserting another value

Comment: I edited my answer and added another output. Looks OK to me (or perhaps I'm not seeing something obvious).

Answer (score 1):

You are converting `c.virus` into the table and it contains two records that are cross joined to the main table. Hence, You are getting two records (1 record cross join 2 records = 2 records)

You can use `analytical function` as follows:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Province_or_State END AS Province_or_State,
       CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Country_or_Region END AS Country_or_Region,
       CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Lat END AS Lat,
       CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Longt END AS Longt,
       vDate, infection, dead, recovered 
  FROM
 (select c.Province_or_State, c.Country_or_Region, c.Lat, c.Longt,  v.vDate, v.infection, v.dead, v.recovered 
 ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.Province_or_State, c.Country_or_Region, c.Lat, c.Longt ORDER BY V.VDATE) AS RN,
 , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY c.Province_or_State, c.Country_or_Region, c.Lat, c.Longt) AS DRN
  from countries c, table(c.virus) v)
 ORDER BY DRN, RN
/
```

See [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fb1865f32ec23627828488176398df0a)

Comment: I think my question is not very clear I have updated my question by inserting another value.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me up around the day :)